# Quantlib interpolation question

Tags: quantlib

I am trying to use QuantLib to create some curves, but I am finding this error I do not really know how to get around. Say for simplicity this is the example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
using namespace QuantLib;
LinearInterpolation e() {
    std::vector<Time> x = { 0,1 }; 
    std::vector<Real> y = { 0,2 };
    return LinearInterpolation(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin());
}

int main()
{
    LinearInterpolation c = e();
    std::cout << c(0.5) << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me an error: "Debug assertion failed. Vector iterator + offset out of range."

I can get around it if I change the code to:

```
Real e(Real t) {
    std::vector<Time> x = { 0,1 }; 
    std::vector<Real> y = { 0,2 };
    LinearInterpolation c(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin());
    return c(t);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << e(0.5) << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

but I would like to use the function multiple times, so that would perform the interpolation multiple times (and hence not so efficient). I was wondering if there is a way to return a Real operator I can use throughout only doing the interpolation once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LinearInterpolation` class doesn't copy the x and y ranges.  You have to make sure that the vectors stay alive as long as you're using them.  Instead of a function, you can code a small function object that stores the vectors.